# Install Ruby on Windows issue

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I am trying trying to install Ruby on Win7 64bit with rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p484.exe and/or rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p353-x64.exe. 
During installation I have an error about Ruby not able to make any changes to Registry. After skipping this step I still can run Ruby as :

```
C:\Ruby\bin\gem.bat gem update --system
```

with permission denied (Errno::EACCES)

Note: I am administrator on my System and I run cmd.exe with administrator privileges. Also, I've elevated Ruby folder permissions.
Can somone to give a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using C:\Ruby193 as your directory of installation.

You may find useful to read this manual I have posted:
http://www.slideshare.net/vdimitris/deploying-ruby-onrailsapplicationsonwindowsfordevelopers